# Sequelize notNull Violation when removing child: product.userId cannot be null

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to delete a product of an user but sequelize keeps informing me that `product.userId` must not be null:

```json
{
    "name": "SequelizeValidationError",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "product.userId cannot be null",
            "type": "notNull Violation",
            "path": "userId",
            "value": null,
            "origin": "CORE",
            "instance": {
                "type": "",
                "category": "",
                "balconDirection": "",
                "mainDoorDirection": "",
                "legalDocsStatus": "",
                "furnitureStatus": "",
                "userType": "canhan",
                "id": null,
                "userId": null,
                "updatedAt": "2023-08-16T11:31:55.232Z"
            },
            "validatorKey": "is_null",
            "validatorName": null,
            "validatorArgs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Below are my delete controller and model association:

**product.controller.js**

```js
async function deleteProductById(req, res, next) {

  try {

    const productId = req.params['productId'];

    const result = await req.user.removeProduct(productId);
  
    // const result = await sequelize.query(`DELETE FROM nhatot.product WHERE (id = :productId)`, { replacements: { productId } }); // works
  
    return res.status(200).json(result);
    
  } catch(error) {

    return next(error);
  }
  
}
```

**app.js**

```js
Product.belongsTo(User, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: { allowNull: false } }); // on delete User, remove Product
User.hasMany(Product);
```

Raw SQL query works normally, yet I can't delete a `Product` of an `User` with the user instance: `req.user.removeProduct(productId)`.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

For the `hasMany` association `remove<ChildModel>` method just sets the parent foreign key value to `null` and doesn't delete the child record itself. You should call the instance `destroy` method on the child instance or call the static `destroy` method on the child model with `productId` indicated:

```js
const product = await ProductModel.findById(productId)
await product.destroy()
```

OR

```
await ProductModel.destroy({ where: { id: productId }})
```